# Objective-C runtime issue setting object for NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

I am coding a fairly complex system that uses a lot of metadata to manage dynamic objects.  I am using various objective-c runtime features.  I want to add stuff to mutable dictionaries which are properties within various classes.  I want to do this where I know the class type and I know the property name, but I don't want to 'hard code' the assignment.  If I hard-coded it I could do this:

```
[[(myknownclass*)localClassObjectInstance knownDictionary] setObject:value forKey:key];
```

but what I want to do is something like this:

```
[[unknownClassObjectInstance {aStringContainingTheDictionaryName}] setObject:value forKey:key];
```

How can I reference the mutable dictionary property when I only have the name of the property at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `-valueForKey:` to run the method:

```
[(NSMutableDictionary*)[inst valueForKey:@"whateverMethodName"] setObject:o forKey:k];
```

Or alternatively, you can use `performSelector:`

```
SEL dictGetter = NSSelectorFromString(@"whateverMethodName");
NSMutableDictionary* dict = [inst performSelector:dictGetter];
[dict setObject:o forKey:k];
```